# How to neaten up an arrow diagram in tikzcd

Tags: tikz-cd

### **Problem Description**

I am using `tikz-cd` to draw a diagram. I want to make the following diagram into a symmetric, nice looking form, but I am not sure how to do this.

[image]

### **MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}
\text{M-Theory} \arrow[r, "\text{low-energy limit}"] \arrow[d, "g_s\to 0" ]
& \text{11d supergavity} \arrow[d, "\text{KK reduction on $S^1$}"] \\
\text{IIA} \arrow[r, "\text{low-energy limit}"]
& \text{IIA supergavity}
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome. // Unfortunately we can't copy and compile your code, as some parts are missing. Please Edit and add. Thanks.

Comment: It may already be enough to unsqueeze your diagram using options like `[row sep=3em, column sep=10em]` (to be placed right after `\begin{tikzcd}`).

Comment: @JasperHabicht Yes that gives me something I'm happy with. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Similar as @Bernard answer (+1) but with use of the `makecell` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\[ 
\linespread{0.75}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=huge,row sep=large]
\text{M-Theory} \rar["\text{\makecell{low-energy\\ limit}}"] \dar["g_s\to 0" ']
    & \text{11d supergravity} \dar["\text{\makecell{KK reduction\\ on $S^1$}}"]  \\
\text{IIA} \rar["\text{\makecell{low-energy\\ limit}}"]
    & \text{IIA supergravity}
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Here is a possible solution with the help of the `stackengine` package:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{tikz-cd}
    \usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}

    \begin{document}

    \[ \tikzcdset{column sep/normal=1.8cm, row sep/normal=2cm}
    \setstackgap{S}{1pt}
    \begin{tikzcd}
    \text{M-Theory} \arrow[r, "\footnotesize\Shortunderstack{low-energy\\ limit}"] \arrow[d,swap, "g_s\to 0" ]
    & \text{11d supergravity} \arrow[d, "\text{KK reduction on $S^1$}"] \\
    \text{IIA} \arrow[r, "\footnotesize\Shortunderstack{low-energy\\ limit}"]
    & \text{IIA supergravity}
    \end{tikzcd}\]

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Bernard there are two mistakes: gravity and not gavity.

Comment: @Sebastiano: I hadn't noticed  the secong typo. I'll fix it instantly. Thank you so much, my friend!

Answer (score 5):

You can increase the column separation (and also the row separation)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=8em,row sep=3em]
\text{M-Theory} \arrow[r, "\text{low-energy limit}"] \arrow[d, "g_s\to 0" ]
& \text{11d supergravity} \arrow[d, "\text{KK reduction on $S^1$}"] \\
\text{IIA} \arrow[r, "\text{low-energy limit}"]
& \text{IIA supergravity}
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Splitting the labels across rows doesn't require packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=5em,row sep=3em]
\text{M-Theory} \arrow[r, "\substack{\text{low-energy}\\\text{limit}}"] \arrow[d, "g_s\to 0" ]
& \text{11d supergravity} \arrow[d, "\substack{\text{KK reduction}\\\text{on $S^1$}}"] \\
\text{IIA} \arrow[r, "\substack{\text{low-energy}\\\text{limit}}"]
& \text{IIA supergravity}
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]